# How to override mappings from Vim installed from source and custom mappings from vim-go?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-go

I originally had Vim 7.4 installed on my CentOS machine and recently built Vim 8.2 from source and installed [fatih/vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) from Github. I've set up vim-go as per the official docs and trying to use the line below in `.vimrc`

```
let g:go_def_mode = 'godef'
```

but for some reason with Vim 8.2 I still have ctags mapping enabled for `C-]` when trying to work with `.go` files. Instead of going to the relevant plugin of `godef`, it is searching for tags and fails with error

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found:
```

Output from Vim --version

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc -std=gnu99   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -ldl
```

And the `:set runtimepath?` is showing the below

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/plugged/vim-go,/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/local/share/vim/vim82,/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after
```

How do I override the behavior from the source mappings and have the one with vim-go take priority? How can I remap the configuration?

Comment: While editing a Go source code file (`*.go`), what does the `:map <C-]>` command show you? (It should show you the existing mappings assigned to that key.) What about `:map gd`?

Comment: @filbranden: I see no mapping found for both the commands

Comment: @filbranden: I found the answer myself. For the vim-go plugin, in `.vimrc`, I needed to set `let g:go_def_mapping_enabled`  to 1 previously it was 0. Can I self-answer this or can be deleted?

Comment: Yes, please answer the question! Glad you found the source of your issue.